# Running bitcoind getaccountaddress

Tags: bitcoind

When I run

bitcoind getaccountaddress

I get this error

```
error: {"code":-1,"message":"getaccountaddress \"account\"\n\nReturns the current Bitcoin address for receiving payments to this account.\n\nArguments:\n1. \"account\"       (string, required) The account name for the address. It ca     n also be set to the empty string \"\" to represent the default account. The account does not need to exist, it will be created and a new address created  if there is no account by the given name.\n\nResult:\n\"bitcoinaddress\"   (s     tring) The account bitcoin address\n\nExamples:\n> bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress \n> bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress \"\"\n> bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress \"myaccount\"\n> curl --user myusername --data-binary '{\"jsonrpc\": \"1.0\", \     "id\":\"curltest\", \"method\": \"getaccountaddress\", \"params\": [\"myaccount\"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/\n"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The getaccountadress command needs an argument: a string giving  the name of the account with which you want the new address to be associated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the arguments and commands [here](http://pastebin.com/B7R7MFjQ).

The correct format is: `getaccountaddress "account name" 1Addressgoeshere` where `account name` is either empty by default ie "" and `1Addressgoeshere` is the public BTC address

Answer (score 0):

You can also type `help getaccountaddress` , or any method for more information of the usage of this method.